# My TweetSharp search query won't return tweets when specifying "from:twitterapi"

Tags: vb.net, search, twitter, tweetsharp

I'm trying to return tweets and I get no tweets back when using the following code.  I am able to get results when changing it to something like `#twitterapi`. I'm wanting to get tweets from a specific user though, not search for a hashtag.

Trying to search for tweets from @twitterapi doesn't return anything...

```
    Dim service As New TwitterService("xmxmxmxmxmxmx", "xmxmxmxmxmxmx")
    service.AuthenticateWith("xyxyxyxyx", "xyxyxyxyx")

    Dim SearchOptions As TweetSharp.SearchOptions = New TweetSharp.SearchOptions() With {.Q = "from:twitterapi", .Count = "30", .IncludeEntities = True}

    Dim Tweets As TweetSharp.TwitterSearchResult = service.Search(SearchOptions)

    For Each tweet As TweetSharp.TwitterStatus In Tweets.Statuses
        TwitterName.Text = tweet.User.ScreenName
        TwitterText.Text = tweet.Text
    Next
```

Search for #twitterapi does return tweets...

```
    Dim service As New TwitterService("xmxmxmxmxmxmx", "xmxmxmxmxmxmx")
    service.AuthenticateWith("xyxyxyxyx", "xyxyxyxyx")

    Dim SearchOptions As TweetSharp.SearchOptions = New TweetSharp.SearchOptions() With {.Q = "#twitterapi", .Count = "30", .IncludeEntities = True}

    Dim Tweets As TweetSharp.TwitterSearchResult = service.Search(SearchOptions)

    For Each tweet As TweetSharp.TwitterStatus In Tweets.Statuses
        TwitterName.Text = tweet.User.ScreenName
        TwitterText.Text = tweet.Text
    Next
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or anything I could try? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To return tweets from a specific user, try this instead:

```
Dim service As New TwitterService("xmxmxmxmxmxmx", "xmxmxmxmxmxmx")
service.AuthenticateWith("xyxyxyxyx", "xyxyxyxyx")

Dim tweets As List(Of TweetSharp.TwitterStatus) = service.ListTweetsOnUserTimeline(New ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions() With {.Count = 5, .ScreenName = "twitterapi"})
```

hope this helps

Comment: Can I still use a query on it? I'm wanting to filter out specific tweets by a user.  Similar to what is shown here: https://twitter.com/search-home  based on information here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

Comment: You can loop the tweets in this list programmatically and search for some keywords.. But basically here this get function is only to get 'all of the tweets of this user'